# Makefile and "relocation has invalid symbol index" error

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I was trying to write my first makefile. In my project I have these files:

- main.c
- list.c
- list.h
- Makefile

There is even no function definition or declaration in any of them, just simple `include "list.h"` and clean main to test the compilation process. When I compile these files in console with command:

`gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra main.c list.c`

everything is fine, but when I use my Makefile (in Qt Creator and Gome terminal) I'm getting a lot of errors like:

`:-1: error: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11`.

This is my Makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-std=c99 -Wall -Wextra
LDFLAGS=

all: listtest

listtest: main.o list.o
    $(CC) main.o list.o -o listtest

main.o: main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.c

list.o: list.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) list.c

clean:
    rm -rf *o listtest
```

This is a makefile tutorial I was using to create it. What's wrong with this makefile and how can I fix it?

http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/

Comment: You don't need targets for `main.o` and `list.o`. make has implicit rules that will do the right thing.

Comment: @juanchopanza The above rules are different from [make's built-in rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules).

Comment: @WhozCraig _and clean main to test the compilation process_. With `-c` command it is working. I'm not sure why there is no this option in tutorial. Maybe because author is using g++.

Comment: @python I totally spaced there is no `-c` in the single targets. duh. Without that each single-target will try and link, which would be bad. You're right that it belongs there.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin And the above rules don't work. The implicit one, `$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c` should do a better job.

Comment: The tutorial does have `-c` in the rules. It is just buried in `CFLAGS`. That second-to-last tutorial makefile is fairly poor (which isn't surprising as they often are) but at least the final example is a little better (though still not great).

Comment: You are right. I missed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed `-c` in your `.o` rules:

```
main.o: main.c
    $(CC) -c -o main.o $(CFLAGS) main.c

list.o: list.c
    $(CC) -c -o list.o $(CFLAGS) list.c
```

A better rule is:

```
%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

This pattern rule is essentially the built-in rule for building `.o` from `.c`, see [make's Catalogue of Implicit Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules). In other words, you don't need to write any of the above rules.

---

A much better rule is:

```
%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -MD -MP -MF ${@:.o=.d} $<
```

This automatically generates dependencies for you. These dependencies need to be included into makefile (on subsequent runs):

```
-include $(wildcard *.d)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
here are two reallife, working make files

SHELL = /bin/sh



SRC := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)
DEP := $(SRC:.c=.d)
INC := $(SRC:.c=.h)


MAKE    :=  /usr/bin/make

CC      :=  /usr/bin/gcc

CP      :=  cp

MV      :=  mv

LDFLAGS :=  -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/lib

DEBUG   :=  -ggdb3

CCFLAGS :=  $(DEBUG) -Wall -W

#CPPFLAGS += =MD

LIBS    :=  -lssl -ldl -lrt -lz -lc -lm



.PHONY: AllDirectories
# the following statement needs to be edited as 
# subdirectories are added/deleted/re-named

AllDirectories :=  \
    Main_Scheduler \
    Communication  \
    Retrieve_GPS   \
    Test_Communication_Dev 



.PHONY: all
all: $(OBJ) $(AllDirectories)
    $(foreach d,$(AllDirectories), \
    ( cd $d && $(MAKE) -f ../makefile.bot name=Tsk_$d all ); )



#
# create dependancy files
#
%.d: %.c
    # 
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$;                      \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@;     \
    rm -f $@.$$$$
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========



#
# compile the .c file into .o files using the compiler flags
#
%.o: %.c %.d 
    # 
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I. 
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========
    # 



.PHONY: clean
clean: $(AllDirectories)
    # ========== start clean activities ==========
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(name).map
    rm -f $(name)
    rm -f *.d
    rm -f ../bin/Tsk_*
    $(foreach d,$(AllDirectories), \
    ( cd $d && $(MAKE) -f ../makefile.bot name=Tsk_$d clean ); )
    # ========== end clean activities ==========



.PHONY: install
install: $(AllDirectories)
    # ========== start install activities ==========
    $(foreach d,$(AllDirectories), \
    ( cd $d && $(MAKE) -f ../makefile.bot name=Tsk_$d install ); )
    # ========== end install activities ==========



# include the contents of all the .d files
# note: the .d files contain:
# <filename>.o:<filename>.c plus all the dependancies for that file 
# I.E. the #include'd header files
# wrap with ifneg... so will not rebuild *.d files when goal is 'clean'
#
ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
-include $(DEP)
endif

the above file, in the top level directory,
has the following companion make file in each sub directory


SHELL = /bin/sh


BINDIR  :=  /home/user/bin


.PHONY: all
all : $(BINDIR)/$(name) ../makefile.mak ../makefile.bot


#
# macro of all *.c files 
# (NOTE:
# (the following 'wildcard' will pick up ALL .c files
# (like FileHeader.c and FunctionHeader.c 
# (which should not be part of the build
# (so be sure no unwanted .c files in directory
# (or change the extension
#
SRC := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)
DEP := $(SRC:.c=.d)
INC := $(SRC:.c=.h)


COMMON_OBJ := $(wildcard ../*.o)

MAKE    :=  /usr/bin/make

CC      :=  /usr/bin/gcc

CP      :=  cp

MV      := mv

LDFLAGS :=  -L/usr/local/lib

DEBUG   :=  -ggdb3

CCFLAGS :=  $(DEBUG) -Wall -W

#CPPFLAGS += =MD

LIBS    :=   -lssl -ldl -lrt -lz -lc -lm



#
# link the .o files into the executable 
# using the linker flags
# -- explicit rule
#
$(name): $(OBJ) $(COMMON_OBJ) ../makefile.mak ../makefile.bot
    #
    # ======= $(name) Link Start =========
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJ) $(COMMON_OBJ) $(LIBS)
    # ======= $(name) Link Done ==========
    #



# note:
# using MV rather than CP results in all executables being re-made everytime
$(BINDIR)/$(name): $(name)
    #
    # ======= $(name) Copy Start =========
    sudo $(CP) $(name) $(BINDIR)/.
    # ======= $(name) Copy Done ==========
    #



#
#create dependancy files -- inference rule
# list makefile.mak as dependancy so changing makefile forces rebuild
#
%.d: %.c 
    # 
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$;                      \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@;     \
    rm -f $@.$$$$
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========



# 
# compile the .c file into .o files using the compiler flags
# -- inference rule
#
%.o: %.c %.d 
    # 
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I. 
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========
    # 



.PHONY: clean
clean: 
    # ========== CLEANING UP ==========
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(name).map
    rm -f $(name)
    rm -f *.d
    # ========== DONE ==========



.PHONY: install
install: all

# include the contents of all the .d files
# note: the .d files contain:
# <filename>.o:<filename>.c plus all the dependancies for that .c file 
# I.E. the #include'd header files
# wrap with ifneg... so will not rebuild *.d files when goal is 'clean'
#
ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
-include $(DEP)
endif

The above two make files 
(the main make file, 
when executed, executes each of the subdirectory makefiles.) 
is from a real/working project.  
It creates several executables, 
one in each sub directory, except the 'common' sub directory.
It creates all the dependancy information (the *.d files), etc etc

Your will notice the 'install' target only invokes the 'all' target
as no special install operations were needed.

These two files are for a linux system/GCC/make, 
but should work with minimal changes elsewhere.
There two files include almost everything 
you will need to know about makefiles.
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but I think I'm not able to understand this now... Maybe in some time :)

Answer (score 0):

Might be You'd missed target name. 
In my case this works without errors:

> g++ -o oclb oclb.o  -L/usr/local/lib -locilib

and here are errors "relocation 0 has invalid symbol index...":

> g++ -o oclb.cpp  -L/usr/local/lib -locilib